# Steps for configuring OAuth2 token in 6.7 for mobile App?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to configure login webservices forAndroid/iOS in Hybris 6.7. Can you please share the steps for configuration using oAuth token.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable oauth2 extension for OAuth2 server in hybris. Offical document here: https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/3d3ea6a4d5fa486aa324ce278fa2afc3.html
(You need S-User for access this source)